# Not getting value from a ASPxRadioButtonList inside a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a scenario in which i have a user control having a ASPxRadioButtonList, i have a data source bind to this list.

Now when i select some option in the ASPxRadioButtonList and on update button when i try to get the selected item, it returns null.

i used following code:

```
 int id = ((ASPxRadioButtonList)ucPlannedRelease.FindControl("lstRdoTicketDetail")).Value.ToString();
```

Even i tried to create a function in the control and to get the select item but it always returns null.

I am unable to find where i am doing wrong

Comment: where is your update button on user control or on parent

Comment: I don't know anything about `devexpress`, but do you mean `.Value`? Shouldn't it be `.SelectedValue`?

Comment: @freefaller: DevEx has .Value property

Comment: Ok, apologies, was just a thought